# Density of $C_c^\infty$ in $W_0^{1,2}$

Tags: limits, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set and let $(f_n) \subset L^2(\Omega)$. Suppose there exists $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that
$$\int_{\Omega} f_n \varphi \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} f \varphi$$
for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

> How can we deduce that $$\int_{\Omega} f_n v \rightarrow \int_{\Omega}
> f v$$ for all $v \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ ?

By definition, for all $v \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ there exists a sequence $(v_m) \subset C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ such that
$$\vert\vert v_m - v \vert\vert_{W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)} \rightarrow 0.$$
Therefore—using Lebesgue's dominated convergence—
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n v = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n v_m.$$
If we can switch the two limits, then I believe the proof is complete. But I'm pretty sure that it is not that simple. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Let $\Omega=(0,1)$. Set $f_n(x):= n^3 \chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 f_n \phi \to 0
$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

Let $\psi \in C^\infty(\bar\Omega)$ be a smooth cut-off function: $\psi=1$ on $(0,1/2)$, $\psi\ge0$, $\psi(1)=0$.

Take $\phi(x)=x^{3/2-\epsilon}\psi$, $\epsilon>0$, which is in $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$. Then
$$
\int_\Omega f_n \phi=\int_0^{1/n} n^3 x^{3/2-\epsilon} =O(n^{1/2}) \to\infty.
$$

---

The statement is true, if one additionally assumes that $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^2(\Omega)$. Then the conditions imply $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$
by density of smooth functions in $L^2(\Omega)$. 
This is equivalent to $\int_\Omega f_n\phi\to\int_\Omega f\phi$ for all $\phi\in L^2(\Omega)$.
Hence, the desired estimate follows as $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you. Additionally, is it true that if $\int_{\Omega} f \varphi = 0$ holds for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ (here $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ is given), then $\int_{\Omega} f v = 0$ holds for all $v \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: yes, that's the density argument.

Comment: This might sounds very stupid, but I don't understand how the first integral tends to zero actually.

Comment: @CheeHan I'm not sure about it but: Since $\phi$ has compact support $K \subset \Omega$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n \geq N$, $K \cap (0,\frac{1}{n}) = \emptyset$. Therefore, for such $n$, $\phi = 0$ on $(0,\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: @Gatz' yes, exactly.